# Jenkins не запускается на Centos 7

Tags: centos, jenkins

Есть VPC сервер под Centos 7, бкз GUI. Устанавливаю Jenkins с помощью dnf/yum

```
sudo yum install jenkins
```

открываю порт и запускаю

```
sudo service jenkins start
sudo chkconfig jenkins on
```

команда

```
sudo service jenkins status
```

выводит

```
Active: active (exited)
```

Никак не получается перевести статус в running

Comment: как и всегда: смотрите логи

Comment: Это в первую очередь.  Пустая директория /var/log/jenkins

Answer (score 0):

В общем ерунда оказалась, но может кому-то время сэкономит. Порт 8080 был занят, назначил другой порт